# Sum of sum in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want the sum of the sum value, below query gives the sum of (Jul+Aug+Sep) as total

```
SELECT  `ls_no`,
        `core`,
        `domain`, 
        `Prog_StdName`,
        sum(Jul+Aug+Sep) as total 
FROM `cf_1ls` 
 WHERE `ls_no`='1234' 
  AND `SOF`='1001' 
 GROUP BY domain ORDER BY `id`;
```

Now i need the query to get the sum of total

Comment: Stop. See normalisation.

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you then accept the so the question could be closed. Read [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

If you want total sum, you can omit `group by`.

```
SELECT sum(Jul+Aug+Sep) as total 
 FROM cf_1ls
WHERE ls_no='1234' 
 AND SOF='1001'
```